# Ideals in algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need some hints to solve the next problem:

> Let $A,B$ be algebras over a field $K$. I want to show that $I \subseteq A$ is an ideal if there exists $\rho :A\longrightarrow B$ an algebra morphism such that $\ker(\rho) = I$.

Thanks.

Comment: Of course not for a fixed $B$. Given an ideal $I$ of $A$ you can *find* an algebra $B$ and a morphism $\rho\colon A\to B$ such that $\ker\rho=I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is false, as stated. The correct statement should be:

> $I\subseteq A$ is an ideal in the $K$-algebra $A$ if and only if there exist a $K$-algebra $B$ and an algebra morphism $\rho\colon A\to B$ such that $I=\ker\rho$.

One direction is easy. For the other one, can you give an algebra structure to $A/I$ (quotient group with respect to the addition)?

The statement cannot hold for fixed $A$ and $B$ for the simple reason that there can be *no* algebra morphism from $A$ to $B$ (for example, take $A$ the $2\times 2$ matrices over $K$ and $B=K$), if algebra morphisms are supposed to preserve the multiplicative identity (there can be only the zero morphism in the other case).

Comment: in the counterexample you gave you mean that there can't be an algebra morphism $f:M_2 (K) \longrightarrow K$ cause doesn't happen that $f(A * Id)=f(A)$?

Comment: @Lix There can be no algebra morphism $f\colon M_2(K)\to K$ because $M_2(K)$ is a simple ring, and the kernel of $f$ should be a maximal ideal. But the only proper ideal of $M_2(K)$ is $\{0\}$ and so the morphism would be an isomorphism: impossible because $M_2(K)$ is not commutative.